# Existence of basis for $L^2(\mathbb{S}^1,\mu)$, where $\mu$ is arbitrary, for which Riemann-Lebesgue lemma is true.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Consider the unit circle $\mathbb{S}^1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$. Let $\nu$ be the uniform measure on $\mathbb{S}^1$. Then there is an orthonormal basis for $L^2(\mathbb{S}^1,\nu)$, namely $\{1,z,\overline{z},z^2,\overline{z^2},\ldots\}$ for which the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma is true. That is, if $g\in L^2(\mathbb{S}^1,\nu)$, then we have
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\mathbb{S}^1} f_n(z)~ g(z)~ d\nu(z) 
=0, $$
for $f_n(z) = z^n$ or $\overline{z^n}$.

My question:  Suppose $\mu$ is an *arbitrary* Borel probability measure (whose support is not a finite set) on $\mathbb{S}^1$. Is it possible to find an orthonormal basis for $L^2(\mathbb{S}^1,\mu)$, namely $\{f_n\}_{n\geq 1}$, such that for every $g\in L^2(\mathbb{S}^1,\mu)$
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\mathbb{S}^1} f_n(z)~ g(z)~ d\mu(z)=0?
$$

*Remark:* For $\mu$ supported on a countable set $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ with $p_n = \mu(a_n) >0$, the natural choice of ONB, namely $\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{p_n}}\delta_{a_n}\}_{n \geq 1}$ works.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate your remark, please?  Suppose $g(a_n)=g_n$; then $g\in L^2(\mu)$ implies $\sum_n p_n g_n^2<\infty$, so $|g_n|\sqrt{p_n}\to0$,but you seem to say that $p_n g_n/\sqrt{p_n}\nrightarrow0$.

Comment: @kimchilover: Thanks! You are right, I will edit the question.

Comment: In fact, if $\{f_n\}$ is _any_ orthonormal basis of $L^2(\mu)$, then for  $g\in L^2(\mu)$ we have $\sum_n| \langle g_n,f\rangle|^2=\|g\|^2<\infty$, so $\langle g_n,f\rangle\to 0$.

Comment: @kimchilover: Thanks! You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{S}^1)$ is countable generated, $L_2(\mathbb{S}^1,\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{S}^1),\mu)$ is separable. Once you have a countable dense set $\{\phi_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, you can obtained an orthonormal basis by Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization. In fact, as $\{e^{-\pi n\theta i},n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is uniformly dense (by the Stone Weierstrass theorem), it will also be dense in $L_2$. You can then use GS-method to find an orthonormal basis.

Riemann-Lebesgue will follow from Parseval's theorem.